# group visibility missing options

Tags: profile, groups, search-results

I Would like to create groups "exposed publicy and for listings".
Buit while the option is available in search-form under "Manage Groups", ist not available within the group settings. There I only have "user and usaer-admin only" and "expose publicy"

Answer (score 1):

those are the only two options available on manage group settings